# How would I create a secure firebase database in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How would I make it so that authenticated users can write any contribution, and only users with matching userID can read only their contributions? My database layout looks something like this. Any help would be great

```
-users
---userid
-----contributions
-------example_data: "hello"
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Without that, it's unlikely that we can help better than the Firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started) or one of the many other resources out there.

Comment: Set firebase DB rules ,For e.g :
// Only authenticated users can access/write data
{
 “rules”: {
 “.read”: “auth != null”,
 “.write”: “auth != null”
 }
}
For more info check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security